# Using some C code in C++ and getting Access voilation error

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am trying to use below piece of code from sflowtool.c  in C++ Builder community edition but receiving Access Violation.

```
uint32_t TForm3::getData32_nobswap(SFSample *sample)
{
    uint32_t ans = *(sample->datap)++; // HERE I GET THE ERROR

  if((uint8_t *)sample->datap > sample->endp) {
    SFABORT(sample, SF_ABORT_EOS);
  }
  return ans;
```

Before &sample is passed to above function, it has this

```
    SFSample sample;
    memset(&sample, 0, sizeof(sample))
    sample.rawSample = (uint8_t *) AData[0];
    sample.datap = (uint32_t *) sample.rawSample;
    sample.endp = (uint8_t *) sample.rawSample + sample.rawSampleLen;
    sample.datagramVersion = getData32(&sample);
```

where  AData is of type "const TIdBytes AData"

Can anybody give me some pointers to understand the reason ? iS there any difference c++ handles above code as compare to C ?

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?  Looks like you have strict aliasing issue but with one that's only a guess.

Comment: What is AData ?

Comment: AData is of type TIDBytes, received in TIDUDPServer

Comment: I don't know this data type, it does not seem to be part of sflowtool ? Are you sure that `AData[0]` contains a valid pointer?

Comment: `*(sample->datap)++`.  Well you have a choice of: 1) `sample` is not valid.  2) `sample->datap` is not valid.  I don't see any other choices.

Comment: Just guessing: If `AData` is an array of bytes ( `char`s or something related), then you probably want to set `sample.rawSample = (uint8_t) AData;` ? If this is not the case, could you at least give some reference for your `TIDUDPServer` API you use?

Comment: That generates [bcc32c Error] mainform.cpp(32): cannot convert 'const Idglobal::TIdBytes' (aka 'const DynamicArray<unsigned char>') to 'std::uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') without a conversion operator

Comment: @MichaelBeer `AData` (of type `TIdBytes`) is indeed an array of bytes. `TIdUDPServer` is a component of [Indy](https://www.indyproject.org). `AData` comes from the `TIdUDPServer::OnUDPRead` event, where `AData` is the raw payload bytes of a received UDP datagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to do :

```
sample.rawSample = (uint8_t *) &AData[0];
```

Note the additional `&`.  This means you are setting `rawSample` to the address of the first element in the `AData` array, rather than treating `AData` as an array of pointers and taking the first pointer from it.

Comment: YES that worked too

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Michael Beer and @PaulMcKenzie for the comments, They were enough for me to realize problem is "const TIdBytes AData" . As a quick solution i was able to achive the goal by converting TIDBytes[] to char [] and using char [] further and it works fine

```
  char buf[AData.Length];
  for(int i=0;i<AData.Length;i++)
  {
      buf[i] = AData[i];
  }
  memset(&sample, 0, sizeof(sample));
  sample.rawSample = (uint8_t *) buf;
```

Another "Delphi way" is this which works too

```
  char buf[AData.Length];
  BytesToRaw(AData,buf,AData.Length);
```

Thanks for awesomeness

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: None of this is necessary. The problem is not with `TIdBytes` itself, but in how you are accessing it. Also, `char buf[AData.Length];` is not standard C++.